# Regex in Visual Studio Code Search/Replace to extract files name

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I am looking to replace all my Shopify's asset references with a CDN based url.

**STRING TO CAPTURE**

`{{'220628_sessiproducts_day-11008.webp' | asset_url }}`

**DESIRED RESULT**

`https://cdn.mywebsite.com/220628_sessiproducts_day-11008.webp`

Answer (score 0):

find: `\{\{'([^']+)' \| asset_url \}\}`

replace: `https://cdn.mywebsite.com/$1`